# How to use glob and find brace brackets in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, glob, brackets

I want to use sqlite3 query like this:

`select * from Log where Desc glob '*[ _.,:;!?-(){}[]<>''"]OK';`

to find records which ends with OK, like
`OK`
`asdasda _OK`
`asda (OK`
`dasda [OK`
`dasda ]OK`

but this fails me when i use back bracket in query`...glob '*[ []]OK';`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment hidden in the source code says:

> Globbing rules:
>
> `*`     Matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
>
> `?`     Matches exactly one character.
>
> `[...]`   Matches one character from the enclosed list of characters.
>
> `[^...]`  Matches one character not in the enclosed list.
>
> With the `[...]` and `[^...]` matching, a `]` character can be included
>   in the list by making it the first character after `[` or `^`.  A
>   range of characters can be specified using `-`.  Example:
>   `[a-z]` matches any single lower-case letter.  To match a `-`, make
>   it the last character in the list.

So, your records can be found with `... glob '*[] _.,:;!?(){}[<>''"-]OK'`.